# Integral of $( (f(x)-x)+f^{-1}(x) -x)$

Tags: calculus, contest-math

My question is about problem A3 from the 2022 Simon Marais Math competition.
It is as follows, We have to show that if

$$f(x)= \sin \left(\frac{\pi}{2} \sin \left(\frac{\pi}{2}x \right) \right)$$

and $$g(x)= \frac{2}{\pi}\arcsin \left(\frac{2}{\pi} \arcsin(x) \right),$$

then there are two values of $x$ for which $\int_{0}^{x} (f(t)-t) + (g(t)-t) dt = \frac{(a-g(a))(f(a)-a)}{2}$

$0<a<1$ ($a$ is a fixed number)

The first thing to observe is that $g(x)$ is the inverse of $f(x)$. Then the integral is the difference of the unsigned areas made by each curve with $y=x$. From a location where $f(x)$=$g(x)$ to another location where $f(x)$=$g(x)$ the integral will give you zero. This is because the curves are symmetrical about the $y=x$ line.

There must be some conclusions we can draw from the right hand side. $(a-g(a))$ seems to be the vertical distance from $y=x$ to $g(x)$ and $(f(a)-a)$ is the vertical distance from $f(x)$ to $y=x$.

Due to the symmetry again, the distance between $(a,a)$ and $(a,g(a))$ would be the same as the distance between $(g(a),a)$ and $(a,a)$.

The right hand side allows me to join $(g(a),a)$,$(a,a)$ and $(a,f(a))$ and conclude that it is the area of this triangle.

Likewise the integral by noticing some symmetries and cancelling, we can see the area left is the area bound by $f(x)$,$y=g(a)$ and $x=a$

After this I am not able to proceed further.

I understand I have to show that the area from the integral will be equal at two points to this triangles area but I am not sure how. I could use the intermediate value theorem but that would sort of be directly applying it to the whole problem beforehand making the process till now redundant.

While solving this problem I have located all distances already but the idea of making a triangle, I got from the solution. However I didn't understand how they proceeded. I am looking for a fresh solution.

I am more interested however in a possible direct Intermediate value theorem/rolle's theorem or a like thereof approach any.

Please also explain about how to proceed in proving the fact using the geometric interpretation discussed till now as well.

Edit: I have understood the given solution, the geometric method, completely now. If there's an alternate method I would like to know it.

I'll write what I understood as an answer

Comment: Interestingly enough, I was an invigilator for this exam. The proof is purely "geometric" and you don't require IVT or Rolle. This was a really interesting question and I will consider writing up a good, detailed answer when I have the time.

Comment: They posted their solutions [online](https://www.simonmarais.org/20221.html). You have most of the ideas. It might be better to figure out what you didn't understand and how that worked out, rather than trying to find a fresh solution.

Comment: SMMC problem and I didn't solve it during test.

Comment: Infact among two papers I solved only 1 question which is problem 1 lol!!! During exam

Answer (score 1):

We first note that the integral is $0$ at $x=0$ and $x=1$ due to symmetry in $f$ and $f^{-1}$

If we denote the integral as $F(x)$,

$F(x)= \int_{0}^{x} (f(t)-t)+(g(t)-t) dt$

Then we see that $F(0)=0$ and $F(1)=0$

If we let the area of the triangle be $A$, we can observe that
$F(a)>A$.

Since $F(0)<A<F(a)$, This implies, by the intermediate value theorem, that $F(x) = A$ for some $x\in (0,a)$

Similarly, $F(a)>A>F(1)$ implies that $F(x)=A$ for some $x \in (a,1)$

We can conclude from here that $F(x)=A$ for two points. One in $(0,a)$ and the other in $(a,1)$

Comment: There are convexity issues that need to be mentioned to show that indeed the triangle with area $A$ is *inside* the region bounded between $f$ and $f^{-1}=g$. Other than that, easy peasy